# ksh cannot export variables out of while loop

Tags: while-loop, ksh

I had hard time to read variable "tt" out of while loop in ksh script. See the example, tt is empty out of the while loop

```
#!/bin/ksh
cat file | while read site

  do
  export  tt=10
  echo "tt1 is ${tt}"
  done
echo "tt2" is ${tt}
```

When I run the script, here is what I got:

```
tt1 is 10
tt2 is
```

I had read many similar example, but none of them works. 1. I can not use bash, 2. I must read the $tt out of while loop.

Thank you.

Comment: When I replace `cat file`  with `printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 4 5` and paste the code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ksh_online.php my `tt2` has the value 10.  So I can not reproduce your problem. Perhaps adding `export tt` before the loop will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

The problem is that `cat ... | while read ...` create a sub-process

```
#! /bin/ksh

while read site; do
    export  tt=10
    echo "tt1 is ${tt}"
done < file

echo "tt2" is ${tt}
```